# Form submitting a File field as String

Tags: php, html, forms

What could cause such a problem in this form?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Please select a picure to upload:</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Upload Picture" />
    </p>
</form>
```

file is getting submitted as string and not as file...

var_dump($_POST):

```
array (size=2)
    'file' => string 'Visit Card.png' (length=14)
    'button' => string 'Upload Picture' (length=14)
```

var_dump($_FILES):

```
array (size=0)
    empty
```

Comment: Is your action the same file? Are you doing any types of redirects before your PHP script executes?

Answer (score 1):

Possible fix:

1. `php.ini` is blocking file uploads, check for post_max_size, and upload_max_file_size.
2. `tmp/` is full, or permissions of tmp prevent writing
3. Turn error_reporting on and see if you get anything.

Because files don't come through in the `$_POST`, instead in `$_FILES`.

```
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"];
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024);
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

Comment: Edited, any of this look like it could be the culprit?

Comment: Thanks, file upload is on, file size limit is 2mb, I checked 2 hosts and localhost (wamp on windows as admin), both of them give me this error, so its not permission or free space related... and no errors on report...

Answer (score 0):

Aside from my comment, check your php.ini to see if file uploads is enabled and/or try this first:

Comment: File upload is on and limited to 2mb, my file is 57kb.

Comment: Is your output file writeable by the server? I'd assume it is because that's how Windows rolls...

Comment: And turn on error reporting like Charles said, <?php ini_set("error_reporting", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>